Finding number of occurences of a word in a PDF file
Inside a folder there are plenty of subfolders and inside the subfolders there are plenty of PDF files. Looks like below:
+- SubfolderA
|  +- File1.pdf
|  +- File2.pdf
|
+- SubfolderB
|  +- File3.pdf
|  +- File4.pdf
|  +- file5.pdf
|
+- SubfolderC
   +- File6.pdf
   +- File7.pdf

I would like to find the number of times a specific word e.g. keywordx occurs in these files.

Preferably ignoring to show the files that have 0 hits.
And ideally showing the list sorted, with the max number of hits file displayed first.


Welcome to the site. Please edit your post to show what you already tried and where you faced problems. That way you can avoid receiving answers that you already know won't work, and contributors will know what kind of tools you have available in your installation.

Also make sure to mention your operating system.

Okay, Good points. Newbee mistakes.

You can fix them - click [edit].

Done ! Thanks again

Using pdfgrep and GNU awk and assuming file paths don't contain newline characters:
word="keywordx"
pdfgrep -rPc "\b\Q$word\E\b" | gawk -F: '
  $NF != 0 {hits[$0] = $NF}
  END{
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"
    for (i in hits) print i
  }'


@StéphaneChazelas Thanks for edit. No need to create a file. This is far clearer and better than before. Thanks.

Outstanding!
Worked like a charm

If you have pdftotext installed (it should be in the repositories of most Linux distributions), you can convert the PDF file to text, grep the pattern in the text file and then delete it. Something like this (using GNU grep for the -o):
pattern="keywordx"
for file in */*.pdf; do 
  txt=${file%.pdf}.txt
  num=$(pdftotext -- "$file" 2>/dev/null && grep -o -- "$pattern" "$txt" | wc -l)
  rm -- "$txt"
  [ "$num" -gt 0 ] && printf '%s: %d\n' "$file" "$num"
done 

Or, to include sorting and also an error if the conversion to text didn't work:
pattern="keywordx"
for file in */*.pdf; do 
  txt=${file%.pdf}.txt
  if pdftotext -- "$file" 2>/dev/null; then
    num=$(grep -o -- "$pattern" "$txt" | wc -l)
    rm -- "$txt"
    [ "$num" -gt 0 ] && printf '%s: %d\n' "$file" "$num"
  else
    printf 'Failed to convert "%s" to text\n' "$file" >&2
  fi
done | sort -t: -nk2,2

Note that the sorting relies on your file names not containing :.
But, really, just use pdftotext as suggested by Prabhjot Singh, it is simpler and better.

This worked Okay too. However the list is not sorted in the descending order of number of hits.
@Prabhjot Singh's solution does that as well
Thanks Terdon

@Ronnie see update, I had missed the bit about sorting. But yes, absolutely, Prabhjot's approach is better, no question about it.

+1. I just used pdfgrep command in your code. Stéphane Chazelas edited it. So all the credit goes to both of you. Usually I don't answer bash questions. Thanks.
